# CMake error when try to add external library

Tags: c++, cmake, fltk

I need to add an external library in my project.
Here is the project structure:

```
/- src/
    - my source files here…
 |- dist/
    |- FLTK
        |- lib/
            |- libfltk.a
            |- libfltk_forms.a
        |- FL
 |- build/
 |- main.cpp
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -std=c++17")

find_library(LibFltk ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK/lib/libfltk.a)
find_library(LibFltk_Forms ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK/lib/libfltk_forms.a)

if(APPLE)
  find_library(COCOA Cocoa)
endif()

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK)

add_executable(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/main ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/main ${LibFltk} ${COCOA})
```

Error message:

```
    CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LibFltk
    linked by target "keyplay" in directory /Users/coder/Desktop/sandbox/keyplay
```

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

When I try to compile my project from terminal it works perfect. 
This is how I do it:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -c main.cpp -I dist/FLTK \
    && g++ main.o -o main -L dist/FLTK/lib -lfltk_forms \
       -lfltk_images \
       -lfltk \
       -lfltk_gl \
       -framework Cocoa \
    && ./main
```

What is wrong in my CMakeLists.txt?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) `find_library(LibFltk libfltk.a PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK/lib/)`?

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, it helped me!

Comment: Did it solve the issue? If yes, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Yes, Matthieu, it was the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Matthieu Brucher. Here is correct config:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -std=c++17")
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK)

add_executable(keyplay ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)

find_library(LibFltk libfltk.a PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK/lib/)

if(APPLE)
  find_library(COCOA Cocoa)
endif()

target_link_libraries(keyplay ${LibFltk} ${COCOA})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `find_library` function expects the second argument to be the filename you are targeting (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html), and you need to specify the paths where to look as additional arguments:

```
find_library(LibFltk libfltk.a PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK/lib/)
find_library(LibFltk_Forms libfltk_forms.a PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/FLTK/lib/)
```